# Expiration date from text file in Qt

Tags: qt, date, text, find

I have a text file with article numbers with their expiration date.
Example:

```
123456789    21-9-2014
987654321    7-12-2014
112233445    3-2-2015
```

But I want a list of all articles that are going to expire in 6 weeks (42 days) in a QTextEdit widget. So I tested this with just a QDate widget to check if something is almost expired or not.

```
QDate ExpireDate = ui->date->date();

if (ExpireDate.toJulianDay() - today.toJulianDay() <= 42)
{
    qDebug() << "Expired";
}
```

This worked. But I want all the articles that are almost expiring (6 weeks before) and stored in text file to be displayed in a textEdit widget. But I don't know how to 'find' these articles in a text file and to display them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sample file you provided, I would do the following:

```
QFile file1("test.txt");
if (!file1.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;

QDate today = QDate::currentDate();
while (!file1.atEnd()) {
    QByteArray line = file1.readLine();
    QList<QByteArray> tokens = line.split(' '); // Depends on the file format.
    Q_ASSERT(tokens.size() == 2);
    QString dateString = tokens.at(1).trimmed();

    QDate date = QDate::fromString(dateString, "d-M-yyyy");
    Q_ASSERT(date.isValid());

    if (date.toJulianDay() - today.toJulianDay() <= 42) {
        fprintf(stdout, "Expired\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've tried it, but I get a runtime error `Invalid parameter passed to C runtime function.` and `This application has requiested the Runtime to terminate it in a unusual way.`

Comment: I've fixed it by using not tabs between the article number and date but just a whitespace.

Comment: @sWeer that's why I wrote comment about dependency from the file format. You could split string by the tab character instead: line.split('\t');